# Convert wpdb sql array into php array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, wordpress

With an sql query I'm grabbing the meta_value of a specific row from my wpdb. In sql it's an array, but it outputs in php as a string, like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:10:”02/17/2014″;i:1;s:10:”Thom Stark”;}}
```

How can I convert this into a php array, so I can access the values from array 2's indices? My query looks like this:

```
$tabledata = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$prefix."frm_item_metas WHERE field_id='$fid' AND item_id='$eid'");
$data = $tabledata->meta_value;
echo $data;

outputs:  a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:10:”02/17/2014″;i:1;s:10:”Thom Stark”;}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

```
$string = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:10:”02/17/2014″;i:1;s:10:”Thom Stark”;}}';
$array = unserialize($string);
```

Comment: Awesome. Trying now. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying this:
`   $tabledata = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$prefix."frm_item_metas WHERE field_id='$fid' AND item_id='$eid'");
   $data = $tabledata->meta_value;
   $array = json_decode($data);
   $content = $data;
   foreach ($array as $a) $content .= $a."<br>";
`

But the array isn't being output.

Comment: @Thom: could you try with `unserialize` ? I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Its a serialized array so u need to use unserialize to convert it back to array as

```
$string = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:0;s:10:"02/17/2014";i:1;s:10:"Thom Stark";}}';
$array = unserialize(trim($string));

print_r($array);
```

NOTE : you have `”`  it should be `"`

Comment: The quotes are just stackoverflow smartquoting it.

Comment: Or WordPress rather, from the front-end. They're correct otherwise.

Comment: No it may be while u copied word press never stores with `”` they just do serialize() the array.

Comment: I think I have to go with nauphal's answer because he suggested unserialize one minute before your answer. :( Sorry! Hate these situations.

Comment: Hey thats fine !! U dont have to be sorry for this !! Most important thing it works for u no matter which answer u choose :)

Comment: Very gracious. Thanks again.