# How to convert datas to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm working on a website, and I want to convert those kind of datas from SQL request to a PHP array that I can update as those datas are variable:

```
[[`license_cop_headhunter`,0],[`license_cop_cAir`,0],[`license_cop_cg`,1]]
```

If you had any ideas on how to do ?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use `->pluck` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert wpdb sql array into php array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682602/convert-wpdb-sql-array-into-php-array)

Comment: use json_decode

Comment: So to answer all of you, json_decode won't work as the example I provide is the exact datas I've got in my db. I'm using Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toArray()` method, it will give you array as a result which you can do your work on its result.

for example:

```
$result = User::whereId(Auth()->id())->get()->toArray();
```

you should remember that you should convert collection data into an array, you can not get direct array output as result like :

```
$result = User::where(Auth()->id())->toArray();
```

This will give you an error.

Checkout : [laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray)

Comment: So, I tried your solution, I think it wouldn't work, in my sql i got this datas : 
> [[`license_cop_headhunter`,0],[`license_cop_cAir`,0],[`license_cop_cg`,1]]
And with toArray, it say that it's not an object. Or something wrong with htmlspecialchars, so I don't think it would do it.

Comment: first of all, you should serialize arrays if you want to store them into mysql properly, then you can get them properly by using unserialize in model